# How to swap/move left-right dataitem in kendoListView using angular?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am working with **kendo UI** and **angular Js**. I had to write small code snippets to perform certain tasks like moving selected options/dataitems swapping the options between two `kendoListViews` as stated below image.

[image]

Comment: Is there a question there? Please clarify.

Comment: yes it is question, I done it using angular JS and html select, but i want to do it using kendo UI control and angular JS.